# If $Z_1, Z_2$ are $N(0,1)$ random variables, is it true $Z_1Z_2 \sim X_1X_2$ for any other $X_1,X_2 \sim N(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $Z_1, Z_2$ are $N(0,1)$ random variables, but we assume nothing about whether they are independent, is it true $Z_1Z_2 \sim X_1X_2$ for some other $X_1,X_2$ that are also $N(0,1)$, regardless of whether they are independent as well?

I know that if we have that $Z_1,Z_2$ are independent of each other and X_1, X_2$ are also independent of each other, then it holds, but if they might be dependent, then I am not sure where this dependency would come in on the integral to calculate the product.

Comment: What if $Z_1=Z_2$ while $X_1=-X_2$?

Comment: Often, I think the assumption _is_ that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent, but in elementary texts this is often not mentioned as carefully as it should be. This is especially so if independence is mentioned in the previous example or problem.